# vk mini app не открывается с телефона

Tags: django, nginx, vk-mini-apps

С web версии и с мобильной версии все работает, а в мобильном приложении бесконечная загрузка. SSL сертификат самоподписанный, может в этом дело? В /var/log/nginx/access.log запросы с мобильного приложения не появляются. Когда тестировал приложение с помощью ngrok, все работало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать

Comment: Ну да, сертификат должен быть нормальным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была действительно в самоподписанном SSL сертификате. Получил с помощью Let's Encrypt, все заработало.